# Json find key contain some char and write key and value to new json file with python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, utf-8, python-2.x

I need find if key contain dash, than need to get this key and value to new json file.

this is my code:

```
#coding=utf-8
import os
import sys
import json
import fileinput

file_path = sys.argv[1]
file = open(file_path, 'r')
content = file.read()

dict = json.loads(content, encoding="utf-8")

output = "{"

for key in dict:
    if key.find("-") != -1:
        output = output + "%s: %s" % (key, unicode(dict[key]).encode('utf8'))
        print output

output = output + "}"

output = json.dumps(json.loads(output, encoding="utf-8"), indent=4, separators=(', ',': '), ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')

file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
sort_file = open(file_name, 'a')
sort_file.write(output)
sort_file.close()
```

output file is some kind of:

```
u'login': u".//input[@placeholder='Email/ \u624b\u6a5f\u865f\u78bc/
```

Is any way to convert content_dict[key] to utf-8 char not like "\u78bc"?
and have any good way to find key contain some char and write to new json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Python 2, and want to be able to read and write json files that contain non-ascii characters.

The easiest way to do this is to perform your processing with unicode only, performing file IO in binary mode and converting raw bytes to json after decoding to unicode when reading, and encoding json to bytes before writing to file.

The code should look something like this:

```
  file_path = sys.argv[1]
  # Read data as bytes
  with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
      raw_data = f.read()
      # Decode bytes to unicode, then convert from json.
      dict_ = json.loads(raw_data.decode('utf-8'))

  output = {}

  for key, value in dict_.iteritems():
      # Using the in operator is the Pythonic way to check 
      # if a character is in a string.
      if "-" in key: 
          output[key] = value
          print output

  file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
  with open(file_name, 'ab') as f:
      j = json.dumps(output, indent=4, separators=(', ', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
      # Encode json unicode string before writing to file.
      f.write(j.encode('utf-8'))
```

In this code I've used the with statement to handle closing open files automatically.

I have also collected the data to be written in a dictionary rather than in a string.  Building json strings manually can often be a cause of errors.

Switching to Python 3 would remove the need for separate encoding and conversion steps and generally simplify handling non-ascii data.

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic way (tested with python 2.7) to filter the original dict is:

```
d1 = {'x-y': 3, 'ft': 9, 't-b': 7}
d2 = {k: v for k, v in d1.iteritems() if '-' in k}

print(d2)
```

Output

{'t-b': 7, 'x-y': 3}